# run windows app with windows service

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services, windows

i want run windows application with windows service.
i have a windows service,this service should run windows application every 1 minute.
How to do it?
any solution can solve this problem,
thanks.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] nad [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: i use this:'ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\myprogram.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.ErrorDialog = false;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

Process process = Process.Start(info);'but can't show and not work.

Comment: >but can't show and not work
If you need something to show from the application then add "Allow service to interact with desktop" in "Log On" tab.

Comment: did you expect a window and specified: info.CreateNoWindow = true; ?